# R - scale_x_reordered() function doesn't allow me to change the x-axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't know how to change the labels of my x-axis into the scale_x_reordered() function ? 
The code scale_x_reordered(breaks=surcharge$arret, labels=surcharge$arret_fr) doesn't work and an error message appears.

```
reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}

scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}

ggplot(data=surcharge, aes(x=reorder_within(arret, sqcearr, dir), y=value)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line() +  
facet_wrap(~dir, scales = "free_x", ncol=1) +
scale_x_reordered(breaks=surcharge$arret, labels=surcharge$arret_fr)
```

> Error in discrete_scale(c("x", "xmin", "xmax", "xend"), "position_d", 
>   :    formal argument "labels" matched by multiple actual arguments

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Done ! Thk u ! Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem !

Comment: @Mostafa that's not a rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your code right, the call to `scale_x_discrete` has

The error message is telling you that you are defining the `labels` argument twice in the line

```
ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
```

Since you are passing both a `breaks` and `labels` argument into the `...` of `scale_x_reordered`, that line becomes

```
ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), 
  breaks=surcharge$arret, labels=surcharge$arret_fr)
```

so you are defining `labels` twice.

I would get rid of the `scale_x_reordered` function altogether and perform the operation you want to on the labels right there where you define your ggplot object.

```
ggplot(data=surcharge, aes(x=reorder_within(arret, sqcearr, dir), y=value ) +
geom_point() +
geom_line() +  
facet_wrap(~dir, scales = "free_x", ncol=1) +
scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub("___.+$", "", surcharge$arret_fr), 
  breaks=surcharge$arret)
```

You could also change this line

```
scale_x_reordered(breaks=surcharge$arret, labels=surcharge$arret_fr)
```

to

```
scale_x_reordered(x=surcharge$arret_fr,breaks=surcharge$arret)
```

and this line

```
scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
```

to this

```
scale_x_reordered <- function(x, sep = "___" , ...) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but unfortunately, it didn't work ! :(

Comment: I've taken the functions from there : https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are using 'scale_x_reordered' wrong, you can only pass breaks to it and the labels are produced from the breaks you pass

Comment: I'll try again after a good sleep ! I was also surprised that it didnt work because your explanation seemed very clear to me ! Thanks again for your time  !